# FilterChainProxy does not autowire in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to autowire FilterChainProxy instance as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter( new CustomSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Sep 22 20:08:16 xxxxxx java[21355]: 2017-09-22 20:08:16.953  WARN 21355 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filterChainProxy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

It does not matter in which class I put the FilterChainProxy instance.
I don't use XML to configure my app, all Spring configuration is annotation-based.
How to fix that problem?

Comment: Why do you need `FilterChainProxy` in your configuration? It should not be neccessary. AFAIK the `FilterChainProxy` is created after the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is executed, so you can't inject `FilterChainProxy`.